# Tortoise svn, replace trunk with working version

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Hope someone can help.

I've got an unknown problem with a trunk branch (code problem, not repo).  I've found that checking out an older copy works but can't eyeball exactly what the problem is.

Now what I'd like to do is not just commit recent changes I've made to the check-out, but replace the trunk repo entirely (warts and all) with *this* current, working copy.

Examples I have seen are only to replace the working version with trunk, but not the other way round.  Any suggestions?

Comment: On my quest for a magic 'option' I've simply moved everything in trunk then copied from the good version (tortoise right-click drag, copy) to the new version then committed. I feel there maybe a more eloquent way.

Comment: No, that's basically it. Make sure that you only delete/move the contents of `trunk` but not `trunk` itself, as otherwise no `svn update` will work afterwards even for files that haven't changed in either the "new" `trunk` nor the working copy a user might have.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @MichaelSchlottke.